# Vlookup Check New Line Entry Only in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, spreadsheet

I am only using the formulas on J3 or K3

`J3 =ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H$3:$H,$B$3:$E,3,0)))`

`K3 =ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H$3:$H,$B$3:$E,4,0)))`

[image]

Vlookup only read the first entry as we know which is green and show on J7 or K7

What I am looking for, if a new entry added on "Google Form Data: list".

Which is [ Read2, ok2 ] with same Slip No overwrite the first one and always show current update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete everything in range J:K and paste in J3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(H3:H, SORT({B3:E, ROW(E3:E)}, 5, 0), {3, 4}, 0)))
```